# Getting "Could not start watchman" when trying to deploy Angular CLI app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails/Angular app to Heroku. When I do so, I get:

When it tries the postinstall I get:

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "author-wizard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install -g node-gyp",
    "postinstall": "ng build",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": "3.10.6",
    "node": "6.5.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.3",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

`ng build` works fine locally. Why not on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `"postinstall": "ng build"` to `"heroku-postbuild": "ng build"` and the problem went away.

(To be precise, the Watchman warning persisted but the build stopped failing, which was the main thing I really cared about.)